# Assess correlation between two variables in a polygon vector layer

Tags: polygon, vector, correlation

I have a polygon vector layer, and for each polygon (representing administrative zones) I have 2 quantitative variables. My goal is to formally assess whether there is a correlation between those two variables in the entire dataset.

For instance: let's say that the two variables are the number of car accidents in each polygon/zone, and average sinuosity of the road network in each polygon/zone. What would the soundest approach be to understand if there is a correlation between those two variables?

Comment: Are you sure this is a GIS problem? It seems to me you just need a non-spatial normal statistical analysis.

Comment: Thanks. I do believe that that could be a space-related issue, since the variables are indeed related to space and (I think) the problem and its solution should be framed in a "spatial" analytical framework.

Comment: [Plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot) them, [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis)